# Multiple QnA Services in one Bot using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I have a Bot with luis recognizer & 1 Qna service. The way I currently consume QnA answers is I use luis intent to trigger a dialog flow and just make a simple Http request to QnA. I would like to expand this bot to multiple QnA KB's or multiple services with each on its own KB's.

- Produce info QnA
- Device support QnA
- Visa issue QnA

When I thought about doing this there were some approaches in mind.

**Approach 1:-** Create LUIS intents for above QnA's , copy paste all questions from above QnA's to luis intents and, just use http request to call each QnA.
cons:- Each time qna questions changes, I would have to update luis intents, lots of manual copy work.

**Approach 2:-** [Use https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/Node/samples/QnAMaker](http://BotBuilder-CognitiveServices)

The issue with this is I am not sure if its best practice to add 4 recognizers (1 luis and 3 qna)on bot instance

ex:- 
    var recognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
        knowledgeBaseId: 'set your kbid here', 
        authKey: 'set your authorization key here',
        top: 4});

**Approach 3:-** Use lUIs dispatcher tool but its not GA yet so I can't use it for production application.

Is there any 4th Option ?
Any examples I can get directed to ?
What is the best practice in these kind of scenarios.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: Have you tried to add a waterstep flow, to let your user select a category before he ask a question, and the redirect the question to corresponding QnA base?

Comment: I think that will be not be right use case for this enterprise bot. I have 3-4 more LUIS intents that I didn't mention above which has respective dialogs. So when user types something I can't ask to choose from QnA because I have other features as well.

Comment: Are these LUIS intents previous steps required before QnA mapping? And, is each intent will individually directly to a QnA knowledge base?

Comment: What kind of QnA mapping you are referring to ? as per my post. Approach 1 / 2 or 3 ?

Like i said when user types 'Please turn on tights' - intent 1 is triggered and i have a dialog to handle it.

'give me weather info' - intent 2 is triggered and i have a dialog to handle it.
'book a meeting' - intent 3 is triggered and i have a dialog to handle it.

'give me heath info' - QnA 1 should be triggered 
'give me auto info' - QnA 2 should be triggered

Comment: So, you have a shared LUIS intent for QnAs, and different entities as `auto` and `heath` for dedicated QnA knowledge base?

Comment: Yes, but that is basic Approach 1 I mentioned in my description. 
I am looking for another solution/suggestions.

Comment: @RoyJ I recommend using the 3rd approach. The Dispatch tool isn't in "GA" but it's only a one time process that will take your NLU models and create a new LUIS model with the models' data. It's essentially the same as the 1st approach, but you don't need to manually copy paste all your questions and training utterances.